# Symbolism of number of crows?

Tags: fiction, resources, world-building, symbolism

After having read a few books with themes of witchcraft in them (ie. Terry Pratchett's *Carpe Jugulum*), I have come to want to use some of the symbolism found in those books in my own writing.

What I really would like to use is the symbolism behind a specific number of crows—allegedly it would foreshadow an event or something of the sort. However there are many variants, and I was wondering what the most common ones were.

Comment: Uh. "the most common" use of a crow as a *symbol* is a euphemism for "Negroes". Just saying...

Comment: @Mazura i am pretty sure that crows symbolize death about a thousand times more often in world literature, as they are drawn to rotting corpses

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reference in Pratchett's books (it appears in more than one of his Discworld Witches books) is to the common rhymes regarding Magpies, which are related to crows.

There are several versions of this rhyme, each part of England traditionally had its own.  The references in the Discworld books play upon these differences which will be recognised by all British readers.

One of the most common is:

> One for sorrow,
>   Two for joy,
>   Three for a girl,
>   Four for a boy,
>   Five for silver,
>   Six for gold,
>   Seven for a secret never to be told.
>   Eight for a wish
>   Nine for a kiss
>   Ten a surprise you should be careful not to miss
>   Eleven for health
>   Twelve for wealth
>   Thirteen beware it’s the devil himself.

A shorter version:

> One for sorrow,
>   Two for mirth,
>   Three for a funeral
>   And four for birth.

According to *Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable* it is:

> One's sorrow,
>   Two's mirth,
>   Three's a wedding,
>   Four's a birth,
>   Five's a christening,
>   Six a dearth,
>   Seven's heaven,
>   Eight is hell,
>   And nine's the devil his old self.

There is a good review of the variants and some of the history behind them at a birdwatching website:
https://www.britishbirdlovers.co.uk/articles/one-for-sorrow-magpie-nursery-rhyme

Comment: I have heard the 1st one and many people I know could only remember up to 7 magpies and didn't know it went over 10.  Great answer, and great find on the full rhyme.